# paginate a wrapper class

Tags: apex, pagination

I want to paginate a wrapper class such that when i navigate from one page to another the slected records dont get unchecked in previos page. This is my requirement. i have build only few part, please help me to complete the requirement.

**my controller:-**

```
public with sharing class PaginationExtension {
    Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}
    Public Integer size{get;set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
        get{
            if(setCon == null){
                size = 10;
                string queryString = 'Select Name, Type, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingCountry from Account order by Name';
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));
                setCon.setPageSize(size);
                noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
            }
            return setCon;
        }set;
    }

    Public List<Account> getAccounts(){
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        for(Account a : (List<Account>)setCon.getRecords())
            accList.add(a);
        return accList;
    }

    public pageReference refresh() {
        setCon = null;
        getAccounts();
        setCon.setPageNumber(1);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**vfpage:-**

```
<apex:page Controller="PaginationExtension">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.Type}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.BillingCity}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.BillingState}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!a.BillingCountry}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:panelGrid columns="7">
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="|<" action="{!setCon.first}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="First Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="<" action="{!setCon.previous}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="Previous Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value=">" action="{!setCon.next}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Next Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value=">|" action="{!setCon.last}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Last Page"/>
                <apex:outputText >{!(setCon.pageNumber * size)+1-size}-{!IF((setCon.pageNumber * size)>noOfRecords, noOfRecords,(setCon.pageNumber * size))} of {!noOfRecords}</apex:outputText>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="Refresh" action="{!refresh}" title="Refresh Page"/>
                <apex:outputPanel style="color:#4AA02C;font-weight:bold">
                    <apex:actionStatus id="fetchStatus" startText="Fetching..." stopText=""/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

please help .....

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom  pagination for this and can use iterator to iterate and try this code sample.

**First class**

```
global class CustomIterable implements Iterator<list<AccountInner>>{ 

   List<Account> accs {get; set;} 
   list<AccountInner> accInnerList {get; set;} 
   list<AccountInner> accInnerListRequested {get; set;} 
   AccountInner accInnerObj;
   Integer i {get; set;} 
   public Integer setPageSize {get; set;} 

   public CustomIterable(string sQuery){ 
       //accs = [SELECT Id, Name, NumberOfEmployees FROM Account Limit 36]; 
       accs = Database.Query(sQuery);
       accInnerList = new list<AccountInner>(); 
       accInnerListRequested = new list<AccountInner>();     
       for(Account a : accs) {
            accInnerObj = new AccountInner(false, a);
            accInnerList.add(accInnerObj);
       } 
       setPageSize = 10;
       i = 0; 
   }   

   global boolean hasNext(){ 
       if(i >= accInnerList.size()) {
           return false; 
       } else {
           return true; 
       }
   } 

   global boolean hasPrevious(){ 
       system.debug('I am in hasPrevious' + i);
       if(i <= setPageSize) {
           return false; 
       } else {
           return true; 
       }
   }   

   global list<AccountInner> next(){       
       system.debug('i value is ' + i);
       accInnerListRequested = new list<AccountInner>(); 
       integer startNumber;
       integer size = accInnerList.size();
       if(hasNext())
       {  
           if(size <= (i + setPageSize))
           {
               startNumber = i;
               i = size;
           }
           else
           {
               i = (i + setPageSize);
               startNumber = (i - setPageSize);
           }

           system.debug('i value is =====' + i);
           system.debug('i value is 2==== ' + (i - setPageSize));

           for(integer start = startNumber; start < i; start++)
           {
               accInnerListRequested.add(accInnerList[start]);
           }
       } 
       return accInnerListRequested;
   } 

   global list<AccountInner> previous(){      
       accInnerListRequested = new list<AccountInner>(); 
       system.debug('i value is previous before =====' + i);
       integer size = accInnerList.size(); 
       if(i == size)
       {
           if(math.mod(size, setPageSize) > 0)
           {    
               i = size - math.mod(size, setPageSize);
           }
           else
           {
               i = (size - setPageSize);
           } 
       }
       else
       {
           i = (i - setPageSize);
       }

       system.debug('i value is previous =====' + i);
       system.debug('i value is 2previous ==== ' + (i - setPageSize));

       for(integer start = (i - setPageSize); start < i; ++start)
       {
           accInnerListRequested.add(accInnerList[start]);
       } 
       return accInnerListRequested;
   }   
}
```

**Second Class:**

```
global Class AccountInner
{
    public boolean isSelected {get;set;}
    public Account acc {get;set;}

    public AccountInner(boolean isSelected, Account acc)
    {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
        this.acc = acc;
    }
}
```

**Visual force page :**

```
<apex:page controller="Example1">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:sectionHeader title="Pagination" subtitle="Hi"/>
      <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockSection >
              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accInnerObj}" var="inner">
                  <apex:column >
                      <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!inner.isSelected}"/>
                  </apex:column> 
                  <apex:column headerValue="Account"> 
                      <apex:outputText value="{!inner.acc.Name}" />
                  </apex:column>    
              </apex:pageBlockTable>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>

      <br/>
      <apex:commandButton value="<<Previous" action="{!previous}" rendered="{!hasPrevious}"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="Next >>" action="{!next}" rendered="{!hasNext}"/>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page> 

Corresponding Controller:

public class Example1 {

    CustomIterable obj;
    public list<AccountInner> accInnerObj {get;set;}

    public Example1 () {       
        string sQuery = 'SELECT Id, Name, NumberOfEmployees FROM Account Limit 36';
        obj = new CustomIterable(sQuery); 
        obj.setPageSize = 10;
        next();
    }

    public Boolean hasNext {
        get {
            return obj.hasNext();
        }
        set;
    }

    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return obj.hasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    }

    public void next() {
        accInnerObj = obj.next();
    }

    public void previous() {
        accInnerObj = obj.previous();
    }
}
```

[image]