# How first() and last () page navigation will work with custom iterator

Tags: pagination

I am referring below link for custom pagination for next & previous , but would like to know how first and Last page navigation will work. Any help is appreciated.
[paginate a wrapper class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108823/paginate-a-wrapper-class)

Comment: question is too broad and unclear. Please, specify more details

Comment: I have a list of custom object records which i am displaying it on pageblocktable . 2 fields are editable on the layout and rest other fields are displayed as readonly.  I am displaying records with pagination using custom iterator . The reason for using custom iterator is to persists values between previous and next pages. Previous and Next are working fine with custom iterator Pagination. Now i want to implement first and last methods , so user can click on first and last button to directly go to the first/last pages

Comment: here is what i am using for Next

Answer (score 1):

In the you are referring, there are two `commandButton` with value **'|<' and '>|'**. These value are for First Page and Last Page.

When you use setCon of type `ApexPages.StandardSetController`, There are predefined methods for '**Next**', '**Previous**', '**First**' and '**Last**'. 
Please follow this [link](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/07/14/visualforce-page-with-pagination/) for more details about using `ApexPages.StandardSetController` for pagination.

And In the case of custom iterator, First and Last method will work same as Next() method, Only you need to set your startIndex to '0' in the case of First() and in the case Last() set startIndex to = `sizeOfYourList - pageSize - 1`

Comment: Thansk Vivek, But i am using custom iterator , not standardsetcontroller , the reason is i want to persist chnaged records over pages. so my query is how can  I implement first and last methods using custom iterator.

Comment: In that case, First and Last will work same as next() method, Only you need to set your startIndex to '0' in the case of First() and in the case Last() set startInsex to = `sizeOfYourList - pageSize - 1`

Comment: it didn't work, can you tell me what is wrong in below code.